# iPhone displaying "mobile" website at higher screen resolution

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, web

I'm currently developing a "mobile version" of a website that is primarily targeting more current iPhones (4+), it's my first time doing this.  I'm testing on an iPhone 4S, my understanding is that the screen resolution of that device is 640x920 (when held in "portrait" orientation).  I have everything on the site within a 600px wide container, although when I view it on the phone it seems to display by default in a "zoomed out" state, being that I can still see something like 1000-1200 pixels of content on the screen.

I assume that the iPhone displays sites in this way as many are not built to adapt to it's smaller resolution?  Is there something I'm missing here?  Is there something I set to tell the device to display the site at it's actual resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a viewport meta tag in your html head.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

That tells the browser that the viewport (virtual width) should be set to the device width (physical width).

Comment: Thanks, yeah I just figured that out actually.  When I put that in the 4S displays the site at an even smaller resolution (320x480 I'm assuming).  I would have expected it to display at 640x920 on the 4S.  When I explicitly set the viewport meta tag to "width=920" it does what I expect, strange.